# Bash script - determine if script launched in terminal console or gui

Tags: bash, user-interface, environment-variables

How to find out if script launched using terminal console or without, in gui by .desktop file for example?

I have look over `env` output and some variables looks promising to check, like test $TERM var. But I want known for sure and a compatible/portable way to do it.

This is needed for script what will have two behaviors for user input, fallback to terminal read or gui input.

Comment: Not sure of your OS and environment, but try checking your *"parent process id"* against the output of `ps -aef` to see who you were launched by. In bash, you can do `echo $PPID`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using cinnamon ubuntu, but want to make script portable

Comment: Well, try it and see. It shouldn't take more than 50 seconds ;-)

Comment: Ok, I see /bin/bash :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell What if /bin/bash is a symlink to dash for example? Checking for bash in ps output will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by @LeonidMew is incomplete and somewhat incorrect.

You should not detect GUI by presence of STDIN (that's what [ -t 0 ] test does). There are cases when none of STDIN and GUI are available, e.g. when you run the script over ssh session in non-interactive mode. This happens often for CI deploys.

Correct answer heavily depends on your task, in general there are 4 distinct environments:

1. App is run non-interactively, e.g. from ssh command, spawned as child process without STDIO attached, etc. `GUI is missing, STDIN is missing`.
2. App is run interactively from X-session with .desktop file or alike. `GUI is present, STDIN is missing`.
3. App is run interactively from linux terminal (ssh, bare text console, hosting recovery console, etc.). `GUI is missing, STDIN is present`. App can interact with user in text mode via STDIN.
4. App is run interactively from GUI terminal app, like xterm. `GUI is present, STDIN is present`.

There are 2 basic tests that can help to identify the environment:

1. GUI test - whether app can interact with user using graphical windows: test for `$DISPLAY env variable`.
2. STDIN test - whether app can interact with user using text console: test for file descriptor 0 (aka STDIN) with `if [ -t 0 ]; ...`

Combining these two test will give you the environment:

```
test 1 false + test 2 false: case 1 -- no user interaction available
test 1  true + test 2 false: case 2 -- interact via XWindows
test 1 false + test 2  true: case 3 -- interact via STDIN/console
test 1  true + test 2  true: case 4 -- XWindows or STDIN/console, whichever is preferred
```

Comment: While my answer is suitable for my script, I do accept your answer cause it more helpful in various situations.

Comment: If one has an `ssh -X ...` to somewhere `DISPLAY` is set despite not having a GUI in the immediate execution environment. The above test for `DISPLAY` can check for `SSH_CONNECTION` to disambiguate this scenario.

Comment: My use case is: when the bash script is run from a `.desktop` entry there needs to be a check at script exit to hold the window open so the user can read the output, but when run from the command line, this check is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then echo "in a terminal"; fi
```

That tests file descriptor 0, which is stdin. If you're launching your script as a GUI, that test should be false.

Author: [glenn jackman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3219/glenn-jackman)

> This won't work if the script is run from a terminal, but with input
>   redirected. – Gordon Davisson
>
> so for the purpose of this discussion, terminal emulator is being
>   conflated with linux console, and both are being distinguished from a
>   "gui method" which I'd thought xterm to be, as it opens in a gui... -
>   JosephHarriott

Purpose of this question was writing script interface usable for text or gui if script run by .desktop shortcut or other gui method.

Comment: This won't work if the script is run from a terminal, but with input redirected.

Comment: That's fine with my requirements for my script(where it come from code review site), however I'll add your comment to answer. If you have better solution, go ahead, add an answer.

Comment: For me, in `Arch Linux`, `[ -t 0 ]` is `true` in the `linux console`. So this test fails.

Comment: @JosephHarriott it must be `true` in the `linux console`, and false if script run by `.desktop` shortcut or other gui method

Comment: Ah, so for the purpose of this discussion, [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) is being conflated with [linux console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console), and both are being distinguished from a "gui method" which I'd thought `xterm` to be, as it opens in a gui...

Comment: @JosephHarriott Right. Linux console provides several virtual terminals, and xterm is terminal emulator. Purpose of this question was writing script interface usable for text or gui.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
 $ [ -t 0 ] &&  echo "in a terminal" || echo "something else"
 in a terminal
```